# function limit with parameters.

Tags: calculus

Find $a,b$ such that:

$$ \lim_{x\to + \infty}  \left( \frac{x^2+1}{x+1} -ax - b\right) = 0$$

I have no idea how to solve this exercise. I know how to prove that the limit is $0$ without parameters $a , b.$

Comment: No it isn't, it's $+\infty.$. It only becomes 0 for a specific (nonzero) choice of $a.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to see that the expression is :

$$\frac{x^2(1-a)+x(-a-b)+(1-b)}{x+1}$$

Now you know that the limit of the quotient of two polynomials is $0$ only when the denominator has greater degree than the numerator .

This means that the numerator has degree $0$ so the $x^2$ and $x$ coefficients must vanish .

$$1-a=0$$ and also :
$$-a-b=0$$

Thus the numbers are $a=1$ and $b=-1$ .

Comment: Because if the polynomial has degree $0$ than all terms of higher degree must vanish . This means that their respective coefficients vanish .

Comment: thanks you ! but why you decide that the numerator has to be 0 ? it's only one option I think... maybe it can be smaller than the denominator and != 0 ?

Comment: I'm not saying the numerator must be $0$ . The numerator is of degree $2$ and the denominator of degree $1$ but  for the limit to be $0$ the numerator must have a lower degree . This means that the numerator has degree $0$ so the coefficients of the terms $x$ and $x^2$ must vanish .

Comment: thank you. I wish you were my teacher at college

Answer (score 2):

From the beginning: Let $$f(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}- a x-b,$$

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = (1-a) \infty,$$ so we have $a \neq 1 \implies \nexists \lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x).$ So we know $a=1$, which yields:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = -1-b \qquad \text{for } a=1.$$
Therefore, $(a,b)=(1,-1)$ is the only tuple in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfies $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x+1}- a x-b = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Put the entire expression on the same denominator, and choose $a$ and $b$ such that the polynomial in the numerator has the lowest possible degree.

Comment: thank u for your post. what do you mean lowest possible degree?

Comment: First choose $a$ such that the term of the highest degree cancels. Then try to choose $b$ such that the term of the highest-but-one degree cancels as well (if possible). If that works then what you are left with (in the denominator) is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$ax+b=(ax+b)\frac{x+1}{x+1}=\frac{ax^2+(a+b)x+b}{x+1},$$
such that
$$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-(ax+b)=\frac{x^2+1-\left(ax^2+(a+b)x+b\right)}{x+1}.$$
Can you continu from here?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the hint

Comment: The enumerator simplifies to $(1-a)x^2+(-a-b)x+1-b$. Write this as $\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma$. So you want $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma}{x+1}}=0$. Now, what does that say about $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: Also, if you want to figure it out yourself, don't look at the other answers XD

Answer (score 1):

note that $$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}=x-1+\frac{2}{x+1}$$